# firebase function 'npm install -g firebase-tools' error

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-tools

I am working on a flutter project and iIkeep getting this error while trying to install firebase tools.

[image]

I already tried `npm cache clean`

- node version : 21.6.1
- npm version : 10.4.0

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.